# Don't stop application if Spring kafka failed to connect to broker

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

Is it possible to setup Spring Kafka, so if it can't connect to brokers or can't initialize for some other reason - it will not drop whole application ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set `autoStartup` to `false` as indicated in the comment above.

Starting with version 2.2, you can set the `ContainerProperties` `missingTopicsFatal` to false to prevent attempting to check for the topics during startup.